# How to run Jest tests with Node (express.js) backend and create-react-app as frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jestjs

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Clearly React is using Jest in "Client" node_modules. If i try to install Jest for server node_modules (one lvl up), i will get error from React, saying i have duplicate packages up in the tree. How should i run tests for server with Jest? How should i install Jest for server? Or should i? Or i can use the same Jest react uses in "Client" folder? If so, how? What is the command? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 separate dependency trees, avoiding `duplicate packages up in the tree` would look like following:

```
server
  ├──> node_modules
  ├──> index.js
  └──> package.json
client
  ├──> node_modules
  ├──> index.js
  └──> package.json
.gitignore
README.md
```